# Toggle code not working in Internet Explorer, Safari but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: android, html, internet-explorer

This code toggles back and forth between 2 images and works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer or Safari.  Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Thanks

This is the website.   http://readautism.atwebpages.com/index3.html

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Example of How to Play a Sound on Click or on MouseOver</title>
    <script>

    var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
        "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
        "mp4": "audio/mp4",
        "ogg": "audio/ogg",
        "wav": "audio/wav"
    }

    function createsoundbite(sound){
        var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
        if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
            for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
                var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
                sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
                if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                    sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
                html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
            }
            html5audio.load()
            html5audio.playclip=function(){
                html5audio.pause()
                html5audio.currentTime=0
                html5audio.play()
            }
            return html5audio
        }
        else{
            return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
        }
    }

    //Initialize two sound clips with 1 fallback file each:

    var mouseoversound=createsoundbite("whistle.ogg", "whistle.mp3")
    var clicksound=createsoundbite('http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/P05/P0501900.mp3', "whistle.ogg")
    var uniquevar=createsoundbite("bus.wav", "whistle.ogg", "whistle.mp3")
    var uniquevar1=createsoundbite("pizza.wav", "whistle.ogg", "whistle.mp3")
    var uniquevar2=createsoundbite("can.wav", "whistle.ogg", "whistle.mp3")
    </script>
    <script>
    var gStorage = {};

    function toggle(anImage, anAltSrcArr) {
        if (typeof(anImage) === "undefined" || typeof(anAltSrcArr) === "undefined" || anAltSrcArr.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var id = anImage.id;
        var oldSrc = anImage.src;

        if (typeof(gStorage[id]) === "undefined") {
            gStorage[id] = {
                'id': id,
                'origSrc': oldSrc,
                'i': 0
            };
        }

        gStorage[id].i += 1;
        if (gStorage[id].i > anAltSrcArr.length) {
            gStorage[id].i = 0;
        }

        if (gStorage[id].i === 0) {
            anImage.src = gStorage[id].origSrc;
        } else {
            anImage.src = anAltSrcArr[gStorage[id].i - 1];
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body
    <p>

    <img class="with-action" id="image1" name="image1" src="pizza.jpg" onclick="uniquevar1.playclip();toggle(this, ['pizza1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:70px; WIDTH:150px; HEIGHT:150px"/>
    <img class="with-action" id="image2" name="image2" src="can.jpg" onclick="uniquevar2.playclip();toggle(this, ['can1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:370px; WIDTH:150px; HEIGHT:150px"/>
    <img class="with-action" id="image3" name="image3" src="bus.jpg" onclick="uniquevar.playclip();toggle(this, ['bus1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:670px; WIDTH:150px; HEIGHT:150px"/>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this is the code you used??

Comment: yes, this is the code I used.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem to this line.  If I take out "uniquevar1.playclip(); it will toggle between images however I lose the sound of course.  Anyone know how to fix this for Internet Explorer.? <img class="with-action" id="image1" name="image1" src="pizza.jpg" onclick="uniquevar1.playclip();toggle(this, ['pizza1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:70px; WIDTH:150px; HEIGHT:150px"/>

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine in my Safari, have you tried possibly, re-booting or restarting Safari.

Comment: I'm using the latest version and it's still not working after restarting safari.